# jEditable InputType date?

Tags: javascript, html, post, jeditable

I'm using jEditable to edit some fields. As default the input fields become textfields when they get clicked. But I have one field which should be type date. Is there any possibility in jEditable?

`type : 'date'` didn't help

Answer (score 1):

You need to have some hacking into the js file for your jeditable. Then, you can add customized date input just like this one which worked out for me:

```
 $.editable.addInputType('datepicker', {
            element : function(settings, original) {
                var input = $('<input >');

                $(this).append(input);
                return (input);
            },
            plugin : function(settings, original) {
                settings.onblur = 'ignore';
                $(this).find('input').datepicker({
                    'autoclose' : false,
                    format : 'dd-mm-yyyy'
                });
            }
        });
```

Followed some tutorials here : http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/custom.html but had experimented with other input types as well like timpicker for bootstaps and multi selects.

'datepicker' will be the type name. you can change the name of the input type in anyway you like